# Sending multiple transactions in the same block with incremented nonces

Tags: javascript, kovan

I need to send 0.1 ETH to 10 unique addresses from the same address at the same time. I am manually incrementing each transaction's nonce, and the transactions are sent successfully.

However, each transaction is entered into a new block. For example, transaction A in block 1, B in 2, C in 3, and so on. The problem is that this isn't scalable across `n` transactions, because I'd have to wait for `n` blocks to confirm.

Is there a proper way to batch-send ETH so that the collective of transactions confirms as quickly as possible?

Edit: This has only been tested on Kovan. Even with Kovan's 4 second block time, shouldn't transactions sent at the exact same time be included in the same block?

Comment: Yes, don't `await` for the transactions to complete.

Comment: I'm not. They're sent asynchronously at the exact same time.

Comment: You might wanna share how exactly you submit those transactions (that is, if you're hoping to get an actual suggestion on how to change it to fit your goals).

Comment: It is literally called `BatchRequest`: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#batchrequest. And you can never 100% guarantee to have all transactions in one block. It's up to the miner to decide which transactions to include. The only thing you can guarantee is the order by setting the nonce.

Comment: @soliditydeveloper.com yeah, `BatchRequest` does the trick. Although, I can't get a transaction's `confNumber` from a `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction.request()`, only the `txHash` from the callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a solidity contract with one method that receives the addresses and the amounts to transfer, and performs the corresponding transfers.

Then you achieve your objective in a single transaction.

For security reasons I recommend to extend the Ownable contract and use the onlyOwner() modifier:

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/access#Ownable

:)

Comment: Hey bro I have been wanted to do that using a contract. Can you send me examples please? If you want you can DM me user3638836

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around with a similar thing however, on the ropsten network and i get multiple transactions in the same block when testing with sending 100 transactions. I have written the following function that allows me to send an arbitrary amount of transactions to my smart contract at the same time. Perhaps this could be re-purposed for your needs?

```js
async function multipleTx(n) {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    instance.methods
      .addSubmission(i, i, i, i)
      .send({
        from: accounts[0],
        gasPrice: 10000000000,
      })
      .then((receipt) => {
        console.log(receipt)
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All `web3.eth.send()` calls automatically increment `nonce` by your wallet (what wallet provider you are using for this?).

You can simply fire out as many `web3.eth.send()` calls or contract calls as possible and then `await` them as `Promise.all()` to resolve. Miners will fill your transactions in block and try to fit as many transactions, yours or otheres, in a block as possible.

Comment: Thanks. But this would only block my process from continuing until every single transaction has resolved. My question relates to _sending_ the transactions, not _receiving_ confirmations.

Comment: `web3.eth.send()` returns something called `PromiEvent`. You can listen to `event.on("txhash")` to immediately go forward as soon as wallet has a txhash. Depending on the wallet logic this can be before of after the transaction has been broadcasted to the network. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendtransaction-return

Comment: I'm doing that. But I need to wait for `x` confirmations of each transaction, which doesn't help if they're sent in different blocks.

Comment: Your last comment does not make sense. Each transaction has its own confirmation cycle. Just wait that all transactions have current block - mined block > needed confirmations.

Comment: Transactions that are in the same block are on the same confirmation cycle. This solution doesn't put transactions in the same block like `BatchRequest` does. It merely sends them out one at a time and waits for the very last tx to confirm before resolving the promise.

Comment: You are incorrect. Transactions will be in the same block if the mining capacity allows.

Comment: Furthermore it does not change the underlying problem - it is the fastest way if you do not count in gas cost optimizations.

Comment: Based on my tests, the `BatchRequest` gets the collective of transactions mined first relative to invoking `web3.eth.send()` in a loop. For me, looping has also been throwing the error `Failed to check for transaction receipt`. Some GitHub threads have speculated that too many requests in a short period can cause this error.

Comment: In my test, 13 transactions were sent at the same time. Sending a `web3.eth.send()` in an async loop resulted in the 13th transaction 12 blocks behind the 1st transaction. In a `BatchRequest`, the 13 transactions were all included in the same block.

Comment: Is it good enough?

Comment: For the purposes of batch _sending_, it's perfect. The only compromise is that there isn't a `PromiEvent` return from each `.send()` in a `BatchRequest`, because it's really a `.send.request()`.